# Is it dangerous to drive having some engine oil spilled on the serpentine belt?

Tags: oil, serpentine-belt

While filling engine oil some was spilled over and made its way towards the belt, I have absorbed most of it but the belt is still visibly oiled in one segment. Is there a danger of the belt sliding off if driven in this condition ?

Comment: How much got on the belt? Serpentine or V belt?

Answer (score 6):

It is highly unlikely that the belt will come off.

The serpentine belt usually drives ancillaries like the alternator, water pump, air conditioning compressor and the power steering pump.

Oil on the belt could cause the belt to slip.  If it slips while you are turning the steering wheel, then the steering could become difficult to turn due to a loss of power steering.  This could take you by surprise and hence be dangerous.

I would try putting some detergent like washing up liquid on the oil on the belt, run the engine to spread the detergent around, then rinse it off with water.

Keep you hands away from any moving parts while running the engine.